# C warning: incompatible pointer types passing

Tags: c, pointers, parameters, pthreads, incompatibletypeerror

I keep getting an error when trying to compile my code.  The error is as follows :

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing
  'void *(threadData *)' to parameter of type 'void * (*)(void *)'
  [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        pthread_create(&threads[id], NULL, start,&data[id]);
```

I'm trying to pass a struct to the function, `void * start(threadData* data)`, and this keeps throwing me off.  Any ideas?

Comment: The first answer explains how to solve your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's complaining about the thread function (bound to the third parameter of `pthread_create`), you can modify that to take a `void *` argument and then cast it back before doing anything with it:

```
void *start (void *voidData) {
    threadData *data = voidData;
    // rest of code here, using correctly typed data.
```

You *may* also opt to coerce the data pointer (fourth parameter) to the expected type:

```
(void*)(&(data[id]))
```

but I don't think that's necessary since a `void *` is supposed to be freely convertible to and from most other pointers.

---

You can see the problem in this small yet complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

struct sData { char text[100]; };

void *start (struct sData *data) {
        printf ("[%s]\n", data->text);
}

int main (void) {
        struct sData sd;
        pthread_t tid;
        int rc;

        strcpy (sd.text, "paxdiablo");
        rc = pthread_create (&tid, NULL, start, &sd);
        pthread_join (tid, NULL);

        return 0;
}
```

When compiling that, you see:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:20:2: warning: passing argument 3 of 'pthread_create' from
             incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
             In file included from prog.c:3:0:
                 /usr/include/pthread.h:225:12: note: expected
                     'void * (*)(void *)' but argument is of type
                     'void * (*)(struct sData *)'
```

Keep in mind that it's just a *warning,* not an error but, if you want your code to compile cleanly, it's worth getting rid of. Making the changes mentioned at the top of this answer (bar the data parameter casting) gives you the following thread function:

```
void *start (void *voidData) {
        struct sData *data = voidData;
        printf ("[%s]\n", data->text);
}
```

This compiles without warnings, and runs just fine.

Comment: @paxidiablo well i tried that exact thing and it still gave the error on the 3rd parameter, start.

Comment: @jgabb, then you need to add more info to the question. The use of `void *start(void*)` makes it the _exact_ correct type so I'm thinking you've made a typo somewhere or you still have the old declaration in a prototype or something. If the error message is the same, then you haven't changed the code (since it's still mentioning `threadData*`).

Comment: Does this preserve the data in the struct whenever i try to access it? For instance, can i do data->example?

Comment: @jgabb: yes, you cast it to `void*` as part of passing it to `pthread_create`, it passes that on as-is to your thread function, which then casts it back in the first line. Once the thread function has done that, it's accessible as the real structure: `data->somethingOrOther`.